# How are single-stranded binding proteins removed from the lagging strand during DNA replication?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-replication

The lagging strand, downstream of the Okazaki fragment, is covered in single-stranded binding proteins (SSBPs) during DNA replication. What is the mechanism which ensures that SSBPs are removed from the lagging strand to allow for the binding of the next Okazaki fragment?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there has been some evidence that the SSBPs keep the bases facing outwards so DNA polymerase can still replicate the lagging strand with the SSBPs on them. There has also been other evidence that they can pop off spontaneously.

You can learn more about this by watching the lectures on https://www.edx.org/course/molecular-biology-part-1-dna-replication-and-repair

Comment: Your answer may well be correct but there is no way for anyone to know without reference to some external source that supports your answer. At the moment it is likely to be automatically flagged as low quality by the system. Please take a moment to read the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing the sort of answers that are appropriate here, and then edit your answer.